# wso2 emm mdm-admin Rest webservices

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

Good day all,

I am having problems adding Rest Services to mdm-admin

I had some troubles with mdm-android-* I created the service and reference in the permission.xml file

Creating a rest service in mdm-admin it has sefinitin as below

```
@GET
@Path("{type}/{id}/logs")
public List<? extends Application> getDeviceLogs(

    @PathParam("type") String type,
    @PathParam("id") String id)
        throws MDMAPIException {

        List<Application> applications;
        ApplicationManagementProviderService appManagerConnector;
        DeviceIdentifier deviceIdentifier = new DeviceIdentifier();

        try {

            deviceIdentifier.setType(type);
            deviceIdentifier.setId(id);
            appManagerConnector = MDMAPIUtils.getAppManagementService();

            applications = appManagerConnector.getApplicationListForDevice(deviceIdentifier);

        } catch (ApplicationManagementException e) {

            String msg = "Error occurred while fetching the apps of the device.";
            log.error(msg, e);
            throw new MDMAPIException(msg, e);
        }
        return applications;
    }
}
```

It is a clone of the get list of application method with just the path and function name changed.

When I deploy it. my webapp returns a **404** error status Code. when I try to call the function

To replicate this, Download v2.0.1 Open with Netbeans, Modify `WSO2 MDM - Mobile Device Management Admin Services`
Copy and paste one of the rest functions, rename the function Deploy and call that new function

How can I resolve this?

Comment: what path you called?

Comment: {"actionMethod":"GET","actionUrl":"/mdm-admin/operations/android/353007060012943/logs","actionPayload":"null"}

Comment: what branch are you using? master or a tag? since there is lot of ongoing development in master branch, this may changed. I will check and let you know. Sorry for the delay happened.

Comment: I am noy using the master I am using the 2.0.1 Release. and Its ok just that i am on a tight leash to get it up and running

Comment: Your code is working properly for me without any issue. Could you post the curl command you used and permission entry in permission.xml?

Comment: the problem is the permision entry I dont know how to add the mdm admin permision using PathParams copy your section and show me please

Comment: added it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code snippet is working for me without any issue. You need to add permission entry in permission.xml as follows to make this work

```
<Permission>
    <name>log device</name>
    <path>/device-mgt/emm-admin/devices/logs</path>
    <url>/operations/*/*/logs</url>
    <method>GET</method>
</Permission>
```

The curl command I used is as below. don't forget to add a content type as application/json.

```
curl -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer 3c28103c1992c9e57d7091fb9f38732e" -k -v https://localhost:9443/mdm-admin/operations/android/000000000000000/logs
```

Comment: Lakshman I modified the function to look like this `@GET
    @Path("{type}/{id}/logs")
    public String getLogs(@PathParam("id") String id)
   throws MDMAPIException{
        
    return "[{\"id\":11,\"log\":\"No logs\"}]";
    }`   on running I get this in my console Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

Comment: what is the complete error on log and response you got?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the 404 since you have to included the nely aded rest api permission to the user.

Please include the related permission to the one of the user's role and try that again.

Reffer to the [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM200/Managing+Users+and+Roles) for more info.